# Explicit way to limit scope of changes that apply to beginDelayedTransition

Tags: android, android-animation

Let's have an animate transitions like this:

```
TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet()
    .addTransition(new Fade().setDuration(500))
    // ...
    .addTransition(new ChangeBounds().setDuration(350))
    .setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(
    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout_id), set);

findViewById(R.id.child_layout_id).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
// ...
```

---

Method **`beginDelayedTransition`** is ...

> Convenience method to animate to a new scene defined by all changes
>   within the given scene root between calling this method and the next
>   rendering frame. Calling this method causes TransitionManager to
>   capture current values in the scene root and then post a request to
>   run a transition on the next frame. At that time, the new values in
>   the scene root will be captured and changes will be animated. There is
>   no need to create a Scene; it is implied by changes which take place
>   between calling this method and the next frame when the transition
>   begins.

---

Is there some **explicit** way to end the scope of changes that apply to this method?

This method supposed to be smart and most likely it is smart enough, but I like to have a full control over it anyway. I want to keep using `beginDelayedTransition`, but with an option to end the scope of changes that will be animated.

I tried to use `beginDelayedTransition(null)`,but `null` is not allowed, so that is not a way to go. How can I gain a full control over this stuff?

Comment: what do you mean by: `"end the scope of changes"`?

Comment: @pskink - Method `beginDelayedTransition` is looking for changes which take place after calling this method. I want to explicitly limit the range of code that it would apply to. So any changes within such layout after some point will not be part of the transition.

Comment: see `Transition#captureStartValues` / `Transition#captureEndValues`, also you can exclude some children of given target by calling `Transition#exclude*` methods

Comment: @pskink - Excluding children is not an option in my case, because some changes of such children I need to have as a part of the transition, while some later in code should not be its part.

Comment: I need this possibility too.

Comment: if you don't want some changes to be captured by transitions, (if this is an option for you) you can try calling `view.post { some changes here }` right after `beginDelayedTransition()`. This way they *should not* be captured as end values, I'm not sure though :) ...